# Panel alignment error with respect to label

Tags: c#, winforms, alignment

I am adding a new way to distinguish the user privileges in my program.

It is a small circular panel that appears after the username and that changes color depending on its privileges and that is shown after the user nick leaving a spacing of 5 pixels
:

```
 private void SetNick(string nick)
 {
      this.NickLabel.Text = nick;
      this.NickLabel.Left = ((this.ProfilePicturePanel.ClientSize.Width - this.NickLabel.Width) / 2) - 5;
      Hector.Framework.Utils.Ellipse.Apply(this.BadgePanel, 6);
      this.BadgePanel.Top = this.NickLabel.Top + 3;
      this.BadgePanel.Left = this.NickLabel.Width + this.BadgePanel.Width + 5;
 }
```

The nick of the user has a minimum of 3 characters and a maximum of 6 characters, then when the nickname has 6 characters (example: Jhon S), the panel is aligned correctly:

[image]

But if the nickname have 3 characters (example: Ben), then this happens:

[image]

It is assumed that the panel should always be shown near the label leaving a space of 5 pixels even if the label changes its content.

> Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can simply use `FlowLayoutPanel` or `TableLayoutPanel`.

Comment: With `Margin.Left` 5px for badge (continuous to @RezaAghaei comment)

Comment: Keep in mind that when using non fixed width fonts, character sizes are not the same width as other characters.  So "W" won't be the same width as "I" for example.  So if you are doing any calculations assuming a character width, your math will be wrong when the characters change.  Use TextRenderer.MeasureText to get the width of text in a specific font.  The label should handle this though, so if your anchors are set right it should work.  If not, you might want to override the label control, and override Paint and draw your badge in there manually, then you have a new control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the Label Control and write your own implementation that draws your badge directly in the Label.  Here's a simple example.

```
public class LabelWithBadge : Label
{
    public Color BadgeColor { get; set; }
    private Size BadgeSize { get; set; }
    public LabelWithBadge()
    {            
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        if (BadgeColor == null)
            BadgeColor = Color.Red;
        if (BadgeSize == null)
            BadgeSize = new Size(20, 20);
    }

    protected override Size SizeFromClientSize(Size clientSize)
    {
        var textSize = TextRenderer.MeasureText("doesn't matter", this.Font);
        this.BadgeSize = new Size(textSize.Height, textSize.Height);
        var baseSize = base.SizeFromClientSize(clientSize);
        return new Size(baseSize.Width + BadgeSize.Width, baseSize.Height);           
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(this.BadgeColor), this.ClientSize.Width - this.BadgeSize.Width, 0, this.BadgeSize.Width, this.BadgeSize.Height);

    }
}
```

By overriding SizeFromClientSize you can control the AutoSize ability of the label, and pad it to make room for your badge.

If you want to support manual sizing for the badge, then you'll need to tweak this to work with AutoSize off.

Then I set Styles on the control to handle painting.  Overriding OnPaint allows you to draw in the extra padded on in the SizeFromClientSize override.

I added a property for the Badge Color.  The Badge Size is determined by the font on the control using TextRenderer.MeasureText.  So if you make the font bigger, the badge get's bigger with it.

This control will show up in your Toolbox when you build.  Then you can use it like any other label but this one has a badge in it.

[image: LabelWithBadge Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very much friend, it served me